# UITableView using xib file, NSObject subclass and using in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib, nsobject

1. I created a single view project in `Xcode` which by default includes `ViewController` file.
2. I created a `NSObject` subclass named `MyClass`.
3. I `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in `MyClass`.
4. `MyClass` confirms to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource`
5. Implemented the required methods of `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource`
6. I created a `xib` file, and in UIView I dragged dropped the `UITableView`.
7. I set the xib file `files owner` class to `MyClass`.
8. Set the `UITableView` delegate and datasource in xib file.
9. In `ViewController` `viewDidAppear` I did this

   ```
   UIView *subView1=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View1" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
   MyClass *c = [[MyClass alloc]init];
   [self.view addSubview:subView1];
   ```

But I am getting this error on `[self.view addSubview:subView1];`

```
-[ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10027adc0
```

In xcode console I did `po 0x10027adc0` which is `ViewController`

I am trying to create a functionality of UITableView using `xib file` and `NSObject` subclass so I can reuse it where ever I want in `UIViewController` class.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you wrote `numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Comment: @the_UB Yes its numberOfRowsInSection method that I am getting in error message.

Comment: show `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Answer (score 0):

As you created a `NSObject` subclass named MyClass. As well you are binding with TableView Delegate & Datasource. But it is kind of NSObject. Instead of creating `UIView` or `UIViewController` type class.

And, if you want to build code for once & use it for multiple times, so please make subclass of `UITableViewController` instead or generate Category class of `UITableViewController` with extended methods.

Comment: My requirement is not limited to uitableview so I need this solution for multiple files which I will include as a part in my big complex app.